# Vlookup from userform input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a check in my code, with the user input in a textbox, I'm trying to use a vlookup in previous records in a table to check if that unique value as already been used (initialized).

The target range "erpLots" contains text formatted cells, amd after checking using the `VarType()` function I know that assigning `vValue = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value` vValue is a string type, the error that I'm getting "Type missmatch" is when doing the vlookup `If Application.VLookup(vValue, erpLots, 1, False) = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value Then`.

I have a hunch that the error revolves around a type missmatch between the value being searched "vValue" and the target range "erpLots".

Here is the code:

```
Public intA As Integer
Public foundRow As Double

Sub StartButtonClick()

    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stg As String
    Dim erpLots As Range
    Dim vValue As Variant

    Set erpLots = Worksheets("Inspection Data").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    Set ws = Worksheets("Inspection Data")

    rowCount = ws.Range("A111111").End(xlUp).Row

    'Checking the userform request info is complete
    If Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Operator ID"
    ElseIf Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please scan or enter spec. number."
    ElseIf Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please scan or enter ERP Lot #."
    Else
        SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value)
        SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value)
        SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value)
        'checking if ERP Lot # already exist in the list

        vValue = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value
        MsgBox "vValue is: " & vValue

        If Application.VLookup(vValue, erpLots, 1, False) = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value Then
            foundRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value, erpLots, 1)
            Range("G" & foundRow).Value = Now()
            Range("H" & foundRow).Value = Range("G" & foundRow).Value - Range("E" & foundRow).Value
            Range("H" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "h:mm"
            Range("H" & foundRow).Value = Range("H" & foundRow).Value * 1440
            Range("H" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "000.00"
            intA = 2
            ws.Activate
            With ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)
                .Select ' not required to change the focus/view
                ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = foundRow - 1
            End With
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With ws.Range("A1")
            intA = 1
            .Offset(rowCount, 0).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value
            .Offset(rowCount, 1).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value
            .Offset(rowCount, 2).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value
            .Offset(rowCount, 3).Value = Now()
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

My goal is that if the value exist, the information being captured is to be recorded in the same row but different columns, if the value does not exist, the information would become a new record.

Comment: Is the value definitely found when it errors?

Answer (score 0):

If your Application.match() is working, why not dropthe vloopkup and just:

```
foundRow = Application.Iferror(WorksheetFunction.Match(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value, erpLots, 1),0)
```

Then your If statement is:

```
    If foundRow > 0 Then
        Range("G" & foundRow).Value = Now()
        Range("H" & foundRow).Value = Range("G" & foundRow).Value - Range("E" & foundRow).Value
        Range("H" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "h:mm"
        Range("H" & foundRow).Value = Range("H" & foundRow).Value * 1440
        Range("H" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "000.00"
        intA = 2
        ws.Activate
        With ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)
            .Select ' not required to change the focus/view
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = foundRow - 1
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With ws.Range("A1")
        intA = 1
        .Offset(rowCount, 0).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value
        .Offset(rowCount, 1).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value
        .Offset(rowCount, 2).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value
        .Offset(rowCount, 3).Value = Now()
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a countif, as a way to check if the input from the user existed in the target range, and then use that as a condition in the if statement.

```
Public intA As Integer
Public foundRow As Double

Sub StartButtonClick()

Dim rowCount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stg As String
Dim erpLots As Range
Dim vValue As Variant
Dim count As Integer

Set erpLots = Worksheets("Inspection Data").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set ws = Worksheets("Inspection Data")
foundRow = 0
count = 0

rowCount = ws.Range("A111111").End(xlUp).Row

'Checking the userform request info is complete
If Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Operator ID"
ElseIf Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please scan or enter spec. number."
ElseIf Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Please scan or enter ERP Lot #."
Else
    SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value)
    SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value)
    SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value = UCase(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value)
    'checking if ERP Lot # already exist in the list and is coming back from labs

    vValue = CStr(Trim(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value))
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(erpLots, vValue)

    If count >= 1 Then
        foundRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(vValue, erpLots, 0) + 1
        MsgBox "row to update is: " & foundRow
        Range("G" & foundRow).Value = Now()
        Range("G" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
        Range("H" & foundRow).Value = Range("G" & foundRow).Value - Range("E" & foundRow).Value
        Range("H" & foundRow).NumberFormat = "d " & Chr(34) & "days" & Chr(34) & " , h:mm:ss"
        intA = 2
        ws.Activate
        With ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)
            .Select ' not required to change the focus/view
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = foundRow - 1
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With ws.Range("A1")
        intA = 1
        .Offset(rowCount, 0).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Offset(rowCount, 0).Value = SpecEntry.TextBox1.Value
        .Offset(rowCount, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Offset(rowCount, 1).Value = CStr(SpecEntry.TextBox2.Value)
        .Offset(rowCount, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Offset(rowCount, 2).Value = CStr(SpecEntry.TextBox3.Value)
        .Offset(rowCount, 3).Value = Now()
        End With
    End If
End If
```

End Sub